# Adsense display just 4 simple links

Tags: adsense, google-ads-api, ads

I want to add some Adsense in my website but nothing too much intrusive. I see some website with adsense like this :

[image]

How they do that ? The best I can do is :
[image]

That's ugly and big !

Here is the code that I use (from Google) :

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Homepage - Un Bon Matelas -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6260603388131652"
     data-ad-slot="5682235326"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Consider adding the code you are using.

Comment: Yes @Werner sorry, here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The ads I am talking about is actually called "Link units". I cannot be 100% sure because for now my ads are not yet verified ([2-3 days according to Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181956?topic=28897)) and I can only see a yellow rectangle, but it seems like this is the same shape :

[image]

For more info, check out this link : [Link units - AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/15817?hl=en&ref_topic=1307421)

EDIT :

I can confirm you :
[image]